# Can someone explain the last return statement?

Tags: java

Does the -1 in the return statement represent the position of the index ? Im struggling on grasping the need for it to be used.

```
 public static int[] search(int[] arr, int targetSum){
        int left = 0, right = arr.length - 1;
        while( left < right){
            int currentSum = arr[left] + arr[right];
            if (currentSum == targetSum)
                return new int [] { left, right };

            if (targetSum > currentSum)
                left++;
            else
                right--;

        }
        return new int[] { -1, -1};
```

Comment: The final return statement just appears to be a default "catch-all" condition should the left input coordinate not be less than the right coordinate, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Looks like targetSum was not found. -1 is returned for int in many cases when something is not found

Comment: this code also works no matter the number within new int .. I have it running via return new int[]{}; .... weird

Comment: Nothing weird about it.  It's just a flag that says "I couldn't find two numbers in the array that add up to the target sum".

Comment: Is it the syntax `new int[] {....}` that you're unsure about?

Answer (score 0):

The last statement is simply to capture the case when there are no two numbers whose combined sum matches the `targetSum` and thus returns the default {-1,-1} case.